# How can I make a class implement an interface correctly?

Tags: java, class, interface, overriding, abstract

I'm trying to make a class implement an interface correctly but seem to have hit a brick wall. I am not sure if the code I have already written is correct but it was the only way I understood how to approach the task. I have been given an interface with this information:

```
package mvcchords;

public interface NoteStore {
    int getNextNote();
    boolean hasNextNote();
    void noteAdded(int midicode);
    void start(int sortOrder);
}
```

The application displays piano keys which allow the user to click on them, and it saves the order they were clicked and the midicode of the notes for the specific sound. Then when the user clicks play, it recalls the tune in the order the notes were saved. When a user clicks on a note `noteAdded` is called. `hasNextNote` is used to check if it is the end of the saved notes or not. `getNextNote` is used to get the next note from the array list and `start` is called when the user clicks the play button. I have been told the integer `sortOrder` is irrelevant for this part of the task. I have been told that when the play button is clicked it should call the `start` method and then repeatedly call the `getNextNote` method until all the notes have been retrieved.

Below is the code I have written so far for a class to implement this interface;

```
import java.util.*;
import mvcchords.*;

public class MyNoteStore implements NoteStore {

public ArrayList<Integer> Notes;

public void noteAdded(int midicode) {
    Notes.add(midicode);
}

public boolean hasNextNote(int k) {
    if(Notes.get(k) != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public int getNextNote(int k) {

        if(hasNextNote(Notes.get(k)) == true)
            return Notes.get(k);
        else
            return 0;
    }

public void start(int sortOrder) {

    for(int k = 0; k < Notes.size(); k++){
    hasNextNote(k);
    getNextNote(k);
    }
  }
}
```

This code gives me an error saying

```
MyNoteStore is not abstract and does not override abstract method `hasNextNote()` in `mvcchords.NoteStore`.
```

I don't know where to go from here and any help would be appreciated. If further information is needed then I will do my best to clarify any points I have made.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

While you have created methods with the correct names you need to have the correct parameters and return types as well. So in this case you need to alter:

```
int getNextNote(int i);
boolean hasNextNote(int k);
```

to remove the integer parameters.

Basically you need to keep track of the notes played back so far in the class so that you don't need to pass an integer about all the time. You could either use an Iterator or just store a integer to track the last index played. The below method uses an iterator, maybe you should try and create the one with an integer yourself.

```
    public class MyNoteStore implements NoteStore {

    ArrayList<Integer> notes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> playbackIter;    

    public void noteAdded(int midicode) {
        notes.add(midicode);
    }

    public boolean hasNextNote() {
        if (playbackIter != null) {
            return playbackIter.hasNext();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int getNextNote() {
        if (playBackIter != null) {
            return playBackIter.next();
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

    public void start(int sortOrder) {
        playBackIter = notes.iterator();
        while(hasNextNote()) {
            int note = getNextNote();
            //play note
        } 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in the method are different between your implementation and the declaration in the interface.

Comment: Yes after looking online I found that I can't do this, but I am not sure how to make the class correctly besides this. I am not looking to be given an answer, just a hint towards the right direction to go :) Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I do not really understand the problem domain (i.e. I know nothing about pianos and notes). However I would guess that the Notes collection needs to lose its dependency on the key k, so you can retrieve from it without needing to pass it. If Notes is a list, for example, keep the index of the current note in an integer variable (in the class) and advance it as you get the next note). I am also assuming that you cannot change the interface. This means that you have to change the internals of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

your interface defines the methods:

```
    int getNextNote();
    boolean hasNextNote();
    void noteAdded(int midicode);
    void start(int sortOrder);
```

So,

your class has to implement them with the exact definition, which means with the same return type AND parameters. So you can either change them in the interface declaration or in the class implementation.